# System to solve, $6$ equations and $6$ unknonws, not enough indications

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a complicated system to solve. I don't know how to do it at all. Someone can give me indications ?

$e_1 = 1 + \dfrac{1}{2} e_2 + \dfrac{1}{2} e_3$

$e_2 = 1 + \dfrac{1}{3} e_1 + \dfrac{1}{3} e_3 + \dfrac{1}{3} e_5$

$e_3 = 1 + \dfrac{1}{3} e_1 + \dfrac{1}{3} e_2 + \dfrac{1}{3} e_6$

$e_5 = 1 + \dfrac{1}{3} e_2 + \dfrac{1}{3} e_6$

$e_6 = 1 + \dfrac{1}{3} e_3 + \dfrac{1}{3} e_5$

And I have to find $e_4 = 1 + \dfrac{2}{7} e_1 + \dfrac{1}{7} e_2 + \dfrac{2}{7} e_3 + \dfrac{2}{7} e_4$ from the precedent $e_i$, $i \in \{1,2,3,5,6\}$... Someone could help me (with indications) ?

Comment: We find $e_4$ on both sides of your last equation... Is it normal ?

Comment: Yes yes, it's normal !

Comment: Place all the variables on the left hand terms, and start a long gauss-jordan reduction process.

Comment: This might come from the computation of the mean exit time of a Markov chain, in which case you might want to add this piece of context. Anyway, 6 linear equations for 6 unknowns, where is the problem here?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to say that, it doesn't add much to the exercise. I just wanted a method to solve this system and I made it clear that I didn't want it to be done in my place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  subtracting equations $(2)-(3)\,$ gives:

$$
e_2-e_3=\frac{1}{4}(e_5-e_6)
$$

Subtracting equations $(4)-(5)\,$ gives:

$$
e_5-e_6=\frac{1}{4}(e_2-e_3)
$$

It follows that $e_2=e_3\,$, $e_5=e_6\,$ and $(1)$ gives $e_1=e_2+1\,$, so the system reduces to:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin {align}
\frac{2}{3} e_2 &= \frac{1}{3} (e_2 + 1) + \frac{1}{3} e_5 + 1 \\[5px]
\frac{2}{3} e_5 &= \frac{1}{3} e_2 + 1
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to put the system in the normal form and then apply the [Gauss Elimination Procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). The remaining part is just easy computations... Ask in comments if you need help.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2j5Ic2V7wq4) I paste an easy tutorial on the Gauss Elimination

Comment: Thank you ! I will use it !